# Google Blogger And Posts

Tags: blogs, blogger

I have created one blog through google blogger, and created 3 posts in it. When I search for it in google then, It shown my blog and opened my posts.

But now I deleted that post and created new post in the same blog, and now I am trying to open that new post through google, but now it is not showing post directly, instead it is giving me links as follpws :

> ```
>                  no posts : show all posts
>                           home
> ```

when I click on home or show all posts link than only my blog is opening,

Can anyone help me to open my blog post directly instead of this intermediate page, when user click on my blog when he searches through google

Comment: Learn how to use blogs and its summary before using blogs.. It is applicable everywhere in your real life. For your kind info, It does not open that intermediate page for other users. Its only for you it displays.

Comment: do anybody else have any suggessions ?

Answer (score 0):

You should wait for indexing the posts of your blogger into Google search engine. It is necessary to add a sitemap into GWT to quickly index posts. However, If you want to check the indexing post status so just open Google search and type:

`site:yoursite.com` or `site:yoursite.blogspot.com`